# Php put PDO into MVC model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

I'm new in MVC, I try to put my PDO into my Model

something like

```
Model{
    public function connectDB(){... }
    public function prepare(){... }
    public funciton closeDB(){... }

}

//connect DB///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$dsn = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=abc; charset=utf8;";
$username = "member";

$password = "123";
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$SQL = $db -> prepare("SELECT pday FROM pday");
$SQL -> execute();
$db = NULL;
```

How can I put connect DB part into Model's method?

and how can I put prepare, execute and close connection into Model too?

something like...

```
$SQL = new Model;
$SQL->connect_db(); //connect DB part
```

I'm not sure is this right way or are any better way can suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way, in fact.

First of all, consider to create a [Singleton class](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+singleton+database+class) for DB Model.

Otherwise, instantiating an object like in your example, you have to construct the class in this way:

```
class Model
{
    private var $pdo;
    private var $dbHost;
    private var $dbUser;
    private var $dbPassword;
    private var $dbDB;

    public function __construct( $host=Null, $user=Null, $pass=Null, $db=Null )
    {
        if( $host && $user && $pass && $db ) 
        {
            $this->connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
        }
    }

    public function connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db )
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql etc...';

        if( $this->pdo = new PDO( $dsn, $user, $pass ) )
        { return True; }
        else
        { return False; } // or do some errors
    }

    public function query( $arg1, ... )
    {
        (...)

        $this->pdo( $query );

        (...)
    }

}
```

Then you can call your class in this way:

```
$SQL = new Model();
$SQL->connect_db( $host, $user, $pass, $db ); //connect DB part
```

Or directly:

```
$SQL = new Model( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
```

Inside the class, the methods refer to PDO instance using `$this->pdo`